# Python Pandas: How to insert a new column from function of existing column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataset which contains a column containing postcode data.

For example "SW12 0ND" is a postcode from a row in the data.

I want to do several things

- Insert a new column, populated with values obtained from...
- ...a function applied to the existing column...
- ...where the function splits the postcode (string) by space characters and returns the first element

In other words, the new column takes the first part of the postcode: "SW12 0ND" -> "SW12"

Comment: have you tried something along the lines of ```df['postcode_refined'] = df['postcode'].str.split(' ').str[0]```

Comment: Or, you could try [Series.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html)

Comment: @sophocles Can't believe it's so simple